# Different units for the Y variable and X variable in a regression

Tags: regression

Y variable: research and development as a percentage of sales. 
X variable: log sales

Question: If sales increase by 10%, what is the estimated percentage point increase in research and development?

How do you know how to interpret it appropriate to scale?

Comment: Do you mean that sales increases 10% or that log(sales) increases 10%?

Comment: Thanks for asking. It is just sales.

Comment: Then it will matter where sales started. You take the derivative of $Y$ with respect to $X$, but your equation is $Y = a + b log(X)$, meaning that $dY/dX = b/X$. (We often don't talk about units on regression parameters, but the assumption is that the units are whatever would be necessary for the equation to make sense.)

Comment: What does your question have to do with the title?